# Get Matching values checked

Tags: laravel

Im using Laravel and vue to get all the matching checkboxes to be checked but  I have this problem... those should not be checked...
I think the problem is the id of the `:value="{{ $subject->id }}"` is not unique

[image: Those should not be checked]

```
<div class="row">
   @foreach($classes as $class)
       <div class="card shadow mx-2 my-4">
          <div class="card-header bg-light py-3">
              <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox"  id="{{$class->id}}" name="class[]" :value="{{ $class->id }}" v-model="gradeSelected" 
                                     />
                                    <label class="custom-control-label pt-1" for="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->name}}</label>
                                </div>
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">                      
                            @foreach($class->subjects as $subject)
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mt-2">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input @error('subjects') is-invalid @enderror" id="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}" name="subjects[]" :value="{{ $subject->id }}" v-model="subjectSelected" 
                                 />
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}">{{$subject->name}}</label>
                            </div>   
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mr-4"><i class="fas fa-user-edit fa-fw mr-2"></i>Update User</button> 
            <a href="/dashboard" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-user-edit fa-fw mr-2"></i>Cancel</a>                
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@include('partials._profileModal')

@include('partials._addParentModal')

@section('js_index_page')
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:{
                gradeSelected: {!! $user->grades->pluck('id') !!},
                subjectSelected: {!! $user->subjects->pluck('id') !!}
            }
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
@endsection
```

Comment: The value of a checkbox is not relevant. Typically you wouldn't have a value at all.

Comment: @miken32 - what could be the cause of this problem and how to fix it?